# Is it possible to do Equivalence logic simplification with SymPy from discrete variable domains?

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, sympy, simplification

I've been using SymPy to do logic simplification (using their [sympy logic](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html) module and it's working well with boolean expressions.

I'm now trying to tackle a trickier problem, but I'm having troubles framing the problem in a way that is solvable from SymPy:

Let's say I have a logical expression made of equivalences:

```
x == 1 or x == 3
```

In the general case, that's already the simplest form for this expression.
In my specific case though, I have access to the domains of the variables, such as:

```
x = [1, 3]
```

So in this case, knowing that `x` can only have `1` or `3` as possible values, we could conclude that the expression:

```
x == 1 or x == 3
```

is always true, and thus can be simplified.

On the other hand, if `x` could have `1,2,3` as values, then the above expression couldn't be simplified further.

I'm trying to generalise the above problem to handle multiple variables, do you have any idea of how I could frame this problem?

Even some pointers to existing algorithms or similar problems would be extremely helpful

### Things I've tried

I've already looked at the [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), but I'm having troubles framing the problem in a way that takes value domains in consideration.

For example, given our previous expression:

```
x == 1 or x == 3
```

We could decide that:

```
A = x == 1
B = x == 3
```

so that the above expression is equivalent to the binary:

```
A or B
```

But how could I take into account the possible values of X? (1,2,3)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try, for a univariate expression, something like this:

```py
>>> from sympy import Interval, FiniteSet, Or, Eq, S
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> Interval(1,3)-Or(Eq(x,1),Eq(x,3)).as_set()
(1, 3)
>>> FiniteSet(1,3)-Or(Eq(x,1),Eq(x,3)).as_set() is S.EmptySet
True
```